# Split columns at delimiter [::] in MovieLens-1M data in R

Tags: r

I am newbie in R programming, unfortunately I have to processing movieLens-1M data. In here I want to ask how I can split column at delimiter [::] in movies.dat. I have try this code:

```
> moviesDF<-read.delim("movies.dat", sep="|", header=F, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> str(moviesDF)
'data.frame':   3998 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ V1: chr  "1::Toy Story (1995)::Animation" "2::Jumanji (1995)::Adventure" "3::Grumpier Old Men (1995)::Comedy" "4::Waiting to Exhale (1995)::Comedy" ...
 $ V2: chr  "Children's" "Children's" "Romance" "Drama" ...
 $ V3: chr  "Comedy" "Fantasy" "" "" ...
```

The desired output is following below:

```
V1: Movie ID
V2: Title
V3: Genre
```

Additional, my aim is to provide recommendation system

Comment: Here is the start `unlist(strsplit("1::Toy Story (1995)::Animation","::"))`, also see [stringr package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/stringr.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package. Usage would be:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(moviesDF, "V1", "::")
#            V2      V3 V1_1                     V1_2      V1_3
# 1: Children's  Comedy    1         Toy Story (1995) Animation
# 2: Children's Fantasy    2           Jumanji (1995) Adventure
# 3:    Romance            3  Grumpier Old Men (1995)    Comedy
# 4:      Drama            4 Waiting to Exhale (1995)    Comedy
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the import function. `read.delim(sep="|")` is not properly reading the dataset because `|` only delimits the differents values you want in V3. You should import your dataset with `readLines` instead

```
moviesDF <- readLines("movies.dat")
moviesDF <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind",strsplit(moviesDF,"::")),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(moviesDF) <- c("V1","V2","V3")
```